# Upper bound the integral or its PV (or prove that it diverges)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need help in finding an upper bound the following integral (or its Cauchy Principal Value):

$$ \int_0^1 \sqrt{x} \frac{|\ln(\frac{(y^{-1}-1)}{(x^{-1}-1)})|}{|x-y|} dx $$

This integral arises as part of a calculation where we mix Cauchy densities with Gaussian likelihood. I am not sure if this is a non-integrable example as the singularity appears at the end. 
I have tried separating the integral into $\int_0^y$ and $\int_y^1$ parts, and $\int_0^y$ part converges with a nice upper bound $\sqrt{y}/(1-y)$. 
I apologize if this is not an appropriate (or well-put) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $0<y<1$, the integral converges absolutely. Indeed, the singularity at $x=1$ is logarithmic (and hence the integral absolutely converges near $x=1$), there is no singularity at all at $x=0$ (the logarithmic singularity is suppressed by $\sqrt x$), and the only remaining suspicious point is $x=y$. But there we can write 
$$
\frac{y^{-1}-1}{x^{-1}-1}=\frac xy\frac{1-y}{1-x}=\left(1+\frac{x-y}{y}\right)
\left(1+\frac{x-y}{1-x}\right)
$$
and hence for $x\to y$ we have, using the expansion $\ln(1+z)=z+O(z^2)$,
$$
\ln \frac{y^{-1}-1}{x^{-1}-1}=\frac{x-y}y+\frac{x-y}{1-x}+O((x-y)^2),
$$
and we see that the integrand has no singularity at $x=y$.

Comment: Thank you @Vladimir ! This representation is indeed very useful!

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: One more question .. it could be that I am not getting something right. Even with this formula: wouldn't it still involve an integral of the type $\int_0^1 \sqrt x \frac{1}{1-x} dx$ ? Sorry if this is a silly question.